# How to use two sets of data for a ListLinePlot as x and y data

Tags: plotting

I'm new to Mathematica, so I have a quite basic problem. 
I found in the description of ListLinePlot, that one can use pairs of variables `{x,y}` for plotting. But my problem ist, that I don't have these pairs. I just have the data set X and the set Y. How can I now plot Y against X?

Comment: try `ListLinePlot[Transpose[{X,Y}]]` or `ListLinePlot[Thread[{X,Y}]]`?

Comment: Thanks! That works

Comment: `n = 5; X = Array[x, n]; Y = Array[y, n];` then  
`Transpose[{X, Y}] == Thread[{X, Y}] == 
 Table[{X[[k]], Y[[k]]}, {k, n}] == Array[{X[[#]], Y[[#]]} &, n] == 
 MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {X, Y}] == ({X[[#]], Y[[#]]} & /@ Range[n]) == 
 Inner[List, X, Y, List] == Partition[Riffle[X, Y], 2]`